# Reverse assertion to match every part of string that contains specified word (RegEx)

Tags: regex

I would like to match every part of string that is limited by: `^.*||` or `||.*||` or `||.*$` and contains text Alpha.

For example:

```
BetaAlpha||Omega||AlphaBeta||Alpha||Omega
```

Right now I have something like this:

```
(?<=\|\||^)(((?!((?<=\|\||^)*Alpha(\|\||$)*)).)*)(?=$|\|\|)
```

http://rubular.com/r/yLwFDllJaf

It matches everything except parts with `"Alpha"`. I would like to reverse it, but can't figure it out.

Other values in this string could be dynamic, only part with Alpha occur in every string (but in random combination).

Comment: Which regex flavor? And why not just split by `||`?

Comment: Can a single | be part of the string? Can you have an input like "Alpha|Beta||Gamma||Delta" with "Alpha|Beta" being a valid match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex matches with the example you have given through the `rubular`

```
(?<=\|\||^)[^|\s]*Alpha[^|\s]*(?=\|\||$)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. If I may ask about one more thing: how add a negation to this assertion? For example every part that contains alpha, but not contains beta?

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex:

```regex
(?<=^|\|\|)[^|]*Alpha[^|]*(?=\|\||$)
```

Explanation and demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/fL8sK7

Answer (score 0):

If the input cannot contain single "|" (e.g "Alpha|Beta||Gamma||Delta" with "Alpha|Beta" being a valid match), the previous answers are ok.

If the input CAN contain single "|", then this should work (tested in .NET and rubular):

```
(?<=\||^)(?!\|)((?!\|\|).)*Alpha((?!\|\|).)*
```

Tested with "BetaAlpha||Omega||Alpha|Beta||Alpha||Omega||TestAlpha"

Output:

"BetaAlpha", "Alpha|Beta", "Alpha", "TestAlpha"

EDIT: removed unnecessary parenthesis and tested in the rubular.